# images not showing

Tags: html, css

Just adding my site - http://ahardenjr.com - to my live host and noticed my social icons are not showing at the bottom right footer. They worked fine on my test site and local host, but is not showing for some reason on my domain host. Doesn't seem to be any mark up problems that I can find below. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

```
<div class="fadehover"> 

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://facebook.com/ahardenjr" TARGET="_blank"><img class="a" src="./icons/facebook.png" height="25" width="25"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/antonn-harden-jr/24/2a2/b72" TARGET="_blank"><img class="a" src="./icons/linkedin.png" height="25" width="25"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/ahardenjr" TARGET="_blank"><img class="a" src="./icons/twitter.png" height="25" width="25"></a></li>
                </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Check if your src path is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your images.  They are **not** in your icon directory...

```
src="./icons/facebook.png"
```

They **are** in your images directory....

http://ahardenjr.com/images/facebook.png

```
src="/images/facebook.png"
```

Comment: Wow this must be a weird error. I'm looking in my icons and the facebook pngs are there and looks like they have duplicated to my images folder. I will delete and add them again.

Comment: @Ichigo:  **How** are you looking?  Web-page control panel interface?  FTP?  Try refreshing the directory view.

Comment: @Ichigo They are still not in your icons folder.

Comment: @sparky627: I am looking from my dreamweaver ftp remote view. It shows the icons folder with the three images there. Obviously, there is something wrong because you guys say they're not. So I'm clueless.

Comment: @Ichigo:  Don't take our word for it...  Click [this link inside your images directory](http://ahardenjr.com/images/facebook.png) and it **is** there.  Click [this link inside your icons directory](http://ahardenjr.com/icons/facebook.png) and it's **not** there.  Your Dreamweaver remote view apparently is not working/refreshing itself properly.  Try logging into your hosting account from the web page control panel instead.

Comment: Yep don't doubt what you guys say. Took your advice and looked inside my ftp file manager instead on Godaddy.com and the icons show there as well. Never seen anything like this so maybe I need to call the hosting company.

Comment: @Ichigo:  Don't forget to let us know what GoDaddy says (good luck) and don't forget to also accept an answer here.

Comment: Ok we resolved the issue. The problem is within the name "icons" for the folder. For some reason, "icons" is a common name used upon godaddy networks and when I dropped the "s", the file works. He didn't give me the full rundown, but for everyone else, beware of what names you choose for folders.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't in your [icons folder](http://ahardenjr.com/icons/).

When you've put the images in your icons folder it would probably be best to lose the ./ in the path too. Just use "/icons/facebook.png". It would still work with the ./ but there is no need for it.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Yea I thought that too but they are in the folder on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your src path is most likely not resolving properly.  Try removing the "." and see what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is with your path, you need to remove the "." or add one more if you want to comeback from one folder

```
<img class="a" src="../icons/twitter.png" height="25" width="25">
```

or

```
<img class="a" src="/icons/twitter.png" height="25" width="25">
```

Comment: doesn't help if he doesn't even have them on his server. I went in and manually tried that and it made no difference.

Comment: Not sure how your not seeing them on the server. I am looking in my icons folder on dreamweaver remote server and they are there. Something weird is going on.